# having trouble with recognizing the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hi how can I find the dimension of a vector space? For example :
$V = \mathbb{C} , F = \mathbb{Q}$
what is the dimension of $V$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Can you just try and see what basis elements you would need if $V=\mathbb R$, $F=\mathbb{Q}$. The proof is not easy. But I thought maybe this will help you get an idea.

Comment: Please use LaTeX in the future for formatting your questions and also try and give a brief exposition of your own ideas so that others can help you think rather than give an explicit answer.

Comment: you'right sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular example, there are two ways to show that the dimension must be infinite:

$\mathbb Q$ is countable, so for any countable set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}\subset \mathbb C$, the set of linear combinations of elements of that set over $\mathbb Q$ must be countable.  But $\mathbb C$ is uncountable, so it must have uncountable dimension over $\mathbb Q$.

We can find an infinite linearly-independent set of complex numbers over the rationals.  Consider the set $\{\log(2),\log(3),\log(5),\log(7),\log(11)\dots\}$; i.e., the logarithms of the prime numbers.  This is easily shown to be linearly independent using the properties of logarithms and prime numbers.

Comment: yes I think that's true.Now I make a new example to understand that I got it or not! for this space V = C , F = C we have uncountable dimension right?

Comment: $V=\mathbb C$ and $F=\mathbb C$?  A space always has dimension $1$ over itself.  For example, the set $\{1\}\subset \mathbb C$ is a basis for $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: so can you tell me what is different between R -> R and V=R , F=R???

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$?  $\mathbb R$ also has dimension $1$ over itself.

Comment: but It makes the R^2 space which It has dimension 2!

Comment: What?  In what sense does $\mathbb R$ 'make' $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Check this basis for $\mathbb{C}$

> $$ \left\{ 1, i\right\}. $$

Now, you need to know what the definition of dimension is?

Comment: I know the definition of dimension .Basically It's the number of the basis vectors.right?but I really don't how should to find it for my example.

Comment: Please reread the question. This the right answer to the wrong question (or a wrong answer to the right question if you prefer).

Comment: The question says "how can I find the dimension of a vetor space?" You can not know the dimension untill you find the basis. That's why I gave you the basis and I asked you to check the definition of the dimention of a vetor space.  I hope it is clear.

Comment: thx. can u tell me the different between R→R and V=R, F=R ?what's different between these 2 spaces?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal This is not a basis for $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$.  For example, $\sqrt 2\not\in\textrm{span}\{1,i\}$.